# Core Data + Mutex + Deadlock

Tags: ios, core-data, uipageviewcontroller

I'm developing an iPad app centred around a newsletter style interface. I'm using Apple's UIPageViewController to do this.

I'm getting a lot of errors I don't fully understand and I'm hoping someone can help get me on my way to a solution.

While turning the page in this interface, very occasionally (and that's what makes it so frustrating, as it's not easy to replicate) the app freezes. I pause the app in the debugger and this is what it shows me http://cl.ly/image/1y3c2x351t0T.

It's clear to me this is a Core Data related error. It's happened before while doing fetch requests. I thought I solved it but it keeps on returning.

```
- (void)setupBlockViews{
//Setup the block views in the correct order

NSMutableArray *blockViewsInUse = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
for(NLNewsletterPageBlock *pageBlock in self.page.pageBlocks){
    NLNewsletterPageBlockView *blockView = [self blockViewForBlock:pageBlock];
    if(blockView){
        blockView.parentPageVC = self;
        [blockViewsInUse addObject:blockView];
    }
}

//recycle block views if needed
if(RECYCLE_BLOCK_VIEWS){
    NSMutableArray *oldBlockViews = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for(NLNewsletterPageBlockView *blockView in self.blockViews){
        if(![blockViewsInUse containsObject:blockView]){
            [oldBlockViews addObject:blockView];
        }
    }

    for(NLNewsletterPageBlockView *blockView in oldBlockViews){
        [blockView prepareForReuse];
    }
    [self.recycledBlockViews addObjectsFromArray:oldBlockViews];
}

self.blockViews = blockViewsInUse;

[self layoutBlockViews];
}
```

The method above, setupBlockViews is called in the UIPageViewController delegate method pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
                   spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation.

In this particular instance the error occurs while trying to access a fetched property of a NSManagedObject. i.e. self.page.pageBlocks

I have ensured many times that I'm following all the rules of threads, Core Data and managed object contexts, so I don't think it is related to threading and Core Data.

Can anyone make any sense of this? And what could be going on here?

Thanks.

Here's the stack trace:

```
 
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f919b libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 595
    frame #2: 0x013efb01 CoreData`-[_PFLock lock] + 33
    frame #3: 0x013efada CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] + 42
    frame #4: 0x0140457e CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1182
    frame #5: 0x014029c9 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 569
    frame #6: 0x0145ddfa CoreData`-[NSFaultHandler retainedFulfillAggregateFaultForObject:andRelationship:withContext:] + 298
    frame #7: 0x0148b5cf CoreData`-[_NSFaultingMutableArray willRead] + 143
    frame #8: 0x0148baf3 CoreData`-[_NSFaultingMutableArray countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:] + 35
    frame #9: 0x0000858c iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterPageViewController setupBlockViews](self=0x1282ff30, _cmd=0x002e1491) + 206 at NLNewsletterPageViewController.m:408
    frame #10: 0x00007724 iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterPageViewController updateLowFootprint](self=0x1282ff30, _cmd=0x002e0ad7) + 62 at NLNewsletterPageViewController.m:253
    frame #11: 0x0000495b iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterViewController pageForIndex:](, _cmd=0x002e09cc) + 884 at NLNewsletterViewController.m:392
    frame #12: 0x00009fc2 iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterVC_AppleStyle goToPage:animated:](, _cmd=0x002e0afd) + 209 at NLNewsletterVC_AppleStyle.m:163
    frame #13: 0x00006781 iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterViewController thumbnailPVRecievedTouch:withEvent:](, _cmd=0x002e0949, sender=0x128bb9d0) + 667 at NLNewsletterViewController.m:779
    frame #14: 0x02aac705 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    frame #15: 0x019e3920 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    frame #16: 0x019e38b8 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    frame #17: 0x01aa4671 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    frame #18: 0x01aa4bcf UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    frame #19: 0x01aa3d38 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    frame #20: 0x01a1333f UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    frame #21: 0x01a13552 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    frame #22: 0x019f13aa UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    frame #23: 0x019e2cf8 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    frame #24: 0x03472df9 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 339
    frame #25: 0x03472ad0 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
    frame #26: 0x00c80bf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #27: 0x00c80962 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #28: 0x00cb1bb6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    frame #29: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #30: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #31: 0x034717e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #32: 0x03471668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #33: 0x019e065c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #34: 0x00002385 iNewsletter`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff390) + 83 at main.m:16

  thread #3: tid = 0x2203, 0x99d779ca libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d779ca libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
    frame #1: 0x02d3fc2b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 863
    frame #2: 0x02d3f8cc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 61

  thread #5: tid = 0x2403, 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x99d73cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x00caca49 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
    frame #3: 0x00cb18d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    frame #4: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #5: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x06c67310 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 608
    frame #7: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #6: tid = 0x2503, 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x99d73cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x00caca49 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
    frame #3: 0x00cb18d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    frame #4: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #5: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x0259bebe Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 393
    frame #7: 0x024e40d5 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
    frame #8: 0x024e4034 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1304
    frame #9: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #9: tid = 0x2803, 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f919b libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 595
    frame #2: 0x013efb01 CoreData`-[_PFLock lock] + 33
    frame #3: 0x013efada CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] + 42
    frame #4: 0x014040cc CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) lockObjectStore] + 76
    frame #5: 0x0146164a CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _dispose:] + 490
    frame #6: 0x014611c5 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 325
    frame #7: 0x01461077 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext dealloc] + 103
    frame #8: 0x0006927e iNewsletter`-[RHManagedObjectContext dealloc](self=0x0b04c880, _cmd=0x02d4dabe) + 176 at RHManagedObjectContextManager.m:53
    frame #9: 0x014262f1 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext release] + 81
    frame #10: 0x00c8741c CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 108
    frame #11: 0x00d8ed1e CoreFoundation`-[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 158
    frame #12: 0x02aac9ff libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject release] + 47
    frame #13: 0x0248ddcd Foundation`__NSFinalizeThreadData + 1295
    frame #14: 0x00cbf5e2 CoreFoundation`__CFTSDFinalize + 98
    frame #15: 0x9a0fa9c7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_tsd_cleanup + 206
    frame #16: 0x9a0f380f libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_exit + 145
    frame #17: 0x9a0f60b5 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 54
    frame #18: 0x9a0f5e79 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448

  thread #13: tid = 0x2c03, 0x99d76be6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d76be6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    frame #1: 0x00ceecb7 CoreFoundation`__CFSocketManager + 1255
    frame #2: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #15: tid = 0x2e03, 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f8280 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 833
    frame #2: 0x9a17e0e0 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003 + 70
    frame #3: 0x07fcc82b JavaScriptCore`WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 123
    frame #4: 0x07fa0bd9 JavaScriptCore`JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 121
    frame #5: 0x07fcbb8c JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76
    frame #6: 0x07fcc0e5 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21
    frame #7: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #16: tid = 0x2f03, 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f8280 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 833
    frame #2: 0x9a17e095 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
    frame #3: 0x07ed0ad7 JavaScriptCore`JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 439
    frame #4: 0x07ed085a JavaScriptCore`JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 234
    frame #5: 0x07fcbb8c JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76
    frame #6: 0x07fcc0e5 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21
    frame #7: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #17: tid = 0x3003, 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f60ac libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 45
    frame #2: 0x9a0f5e79 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448

  thread #19: tid = 0x3203, 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f60ac libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 45
    frame #2: 0x9a0f5e79 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448

  thread #21: tid = 0x3403, 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f60ac libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 45
    frame #2: 0x9a0f5e79 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448

  thread #22: tid = 0x3503, 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f919b libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 595
    frame #2: 0x013efb01 CoreData`-[_PFLock lock] + 33
    frame #3: 0x013efada CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] + 42
    frame #4: 0x014040cc CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) lockObjectStore] + 76
    frame #5: 0x014219c2 CoreData`_PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 306
    frame #6: 0x01421887 CoreData`-[NSFaultHandler fulfillFault:withContext:forIndex:] + 39
    frame #7: 0x014214c1 CoreData`_PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 225
    frame #8: 0x01421336 CoreData`_sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 70
    frame #9: 0x014521a0 CoreData`_pvfk_3 + 32
    frame #10: 0x000063ab iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterViewController thumbnailPickerView:imageAtIndex:](, _cmd=0x002e0f16, thumbnailPickerView=0x128bb9d0) + 239 at NLNewsletterViewController.m:723
    frame #11: 0x000515c5 iNewsletter`__33-[ThumbnailPickerView reloadData]_block_invoke119(.block_descriptor=0x128c2fc0) + 81 at ThumbnailPickerView.m:230
    frame #12: 0x02d3a53f libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    frame #13: 0x02d4c014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #14: 0x02d3c418 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_drain + 239
    frame #15: 0x02d3c2a6 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_queue_invoke + 59
    frame #16: 0x02d3d280 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 231
    frame #17: 0x02d3d450 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    frame #18: 0x9a0f5e72 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 441

  thread #14: tid = 0x2d03, 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d770ee libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f60ac libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 45
    frame #2: 0x9a0f5e79 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448

  thread #24: tid = 0x3703, 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x99d73cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x00caca49 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
    frame #3: 0x00cb18d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    frame #4: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #5: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x068340b0 WebCore`WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 208
    frame #7: 0x07fcbb8c JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76
    frame #8: 0x07fcc0e5 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21
    frame #9: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344
```

And another stack trace the next time it occurred:

```
thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f919b libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 595
    frame #2: 0x013efb01 CoreData`-[_PFLock lock] + 33
    frame #3: 0x013efada CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] + 42
    frame #4: 0x014040cc CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) lockObjectStore] + 76
    frame #5: 0x014219c2 CoreData`_PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 306
    frame #6: 0x01421887 CoreData`-[NSFaultHandler fulfillFault:withContext:forIndex:] + 39
    frame #7: 0x014214c1 CoreData`_PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 225
    frame #8: 0x01421336 CoreData`_sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 70
    frame #9: 0x014521d0 CoreData`_pvfk_4 + 32
    frame #10: 0x00016617 iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletter isReady](self=0x0b058010, _cmd=0x02679b09) + 53 at NLNewsletter.m:175
    frame #11: 0x0002f7f8 iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterContainerVC displayNewsletter](self=0x10bbe700, _cmd=0x002e4ea8) + 174 at NLNewsletterContainerVC.m:156
    frame #12: 0x0002f743 iNewsletter`-[NLNewsletterContainerVC viewDidFinishPresenting](self=0x10bbe700, _cmd=0x002e1d74) + 79 at NLNewsletterContainerVC.m:145
    frame #13: 0x02aac663 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    frame #14: 0x0000b2f2 iNewsletter`__43-[NLStandarVC presentVC:fromView:animated:]_block_invoke(.block_descriptor=0x10b07830) + 289 at NLStandarVC.m:142
    frame #15: 0x0000b499 iNewsletter`__43-[NLStandarVC presentVC:fromView:animated:]_block_invoke105(, finished='\x01') + 24 at NLStandarVC.m:159
    frame #16: 0x01a2b446 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 223
    frame #17: 0x01a1e3b6 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 237
    frame #18: 0x01a1e554 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 68
    frame #19: 0x018f67d8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284
    frame #20: 0x02d4c014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #21: 0x02d3c7d5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
    frame #22: 0x00cb1af5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1925
    frame #23: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #24: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #25: 0x034717e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #26: 0x03471668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #27: 0x019e065c UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #28: 0x00002385 iNewsletter`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff390) + 83 at main.m:16

  thread #3: tid = 0x2203, 0x99d779ca libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d779ca libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
    frame #1: 0x02d3fc2b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 863
    frame #2: 0x02d3f8cc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 61

  thread #5: tid = 0x2403, 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x99d73cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x00caca49 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
    frame #3: 0x00cb18d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    frame #4: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #5: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x06c67310 WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 608
    frame #7: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #7: tid = 0x2603, 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x99d73cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x00caca49 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
    frame #3: 0x00cb18d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    frame #4: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #5: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x0259bebe Foundation`+[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 393
    frame #7: 0x024e40d5 Foundation`-[NSThread main] + 76
    frame #8: 0x024e4034 Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1304
    frame #9: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #9: tid = 0x2803, 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d7691a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f919b libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 595
    frame #2: 0x013efb01 CoreData`-[_PFLock lock] + 33
    frame #3: 0x013efada CoreData`-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] + 42
    frame #4: 0x014040cc CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) lockObjectStore] + 76
    frame #5: 0x0146164a CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _dispose:] + 490
    frame #6: 0x014611c5 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext _dealloc__] + 325
    frame #7: 0x01461077 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext dealloc] + 103
    frame #8: 0x0006927e iNewsletter`-[RHManagedObjectContext dealloc](self=0x10b14960, _cmd=0x02d4dabe) + 176 at RHManagedObjectContextManager.m:53
    frame #9: 0x014262f1 CoreData`-[NSManagedObjectContext release] + 81
    frame #10: 0x00c8741c CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 108
    frame #11: 0x00d8ed1e CoreFoundation`-[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 158
    frame #12: 0x02aac9ff libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject release] + 47
    frame #13: 0x0248ddcd Foundation`__NSFinalizeThreadData + 1295
    frame #14: 0x00cbf5e2 CoreFoundation`__CFTSDFinalize + 98
    frame #15: 0x9a0fa9c7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_tsd_cleanup + 206
    frame #16: 0x9a0f380f libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_exit + 145
    frame #17: 0x9a0f60b5 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_workq_return + 54
    frame #18: 0x9a0f5e79 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 448

  thread #13: tid = 0x2c03, 0x99d76be6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d76be6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
    frame #1: 0x00ceecb7 CoreFoundation`__CFSocketManager + 1255
    frame #2: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

* thread #15: tid = 0x2e03, 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f8280 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 833
    frame #2: 0x9a17e0e0 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003 + 70
    frame #3: 0x07fcc82b JavaScriptCore`WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 123
    frame #4: 0x07fa0bd9 JavaScriptCore`JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 121
    frame #5: 0x07fcbb8c JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76
    frame #6: 0x07fcc0e5 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21
    frame #7: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #16: tid = 0x2f03, 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d768e2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a0f8280 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 833
    frame #2: 0x9a17e095 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
    frame #3: 0x07ed0ad7 JavaScriptCore`JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 439
    frame #4: 0x07ed085a JavaScriptCore`JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 234
    frame #5: 0x07fcbb8c JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76
    frame #6: 0x07fcc0e5 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21
    frame #7: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344

  thread #17: tid = 0x3003, 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x99d747d2 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x99d73cb0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x00caca49 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
    frame #3: 0x00cb18d4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1380
    frame #4: 0x00cb0f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #5: 0x00cb0e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x068340b0 WebCore`WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 208
    frame #7: 0x07fcbb8c JavaScriptCore`WTF::threadEntryPoint(void*) + 76
    frame #8: 0x07fcc0e5 JavaScriptCore`WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 21
    frame #9: 0x9a0f35b7 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_start + 344
```

Comment: Can you show us the state of all the threads when this deadlock happens? You can press "pause" when the app freezes, and type `bt all` to log the stack trace of all threads at that point. It does look like a deadlock based on the screenshot you have shown.

Comment: Hi anurag, I updated my post with the stack trace of all threads.

Comment: Could you put the whole thing in <blockquote> or <pre> tags so it's easier to read?

Answer (score 3):

I found a piece of code which runs on a background thread that was accessing an NSManagedObject created on the main thread. I missed it before. Mutex error is now gone.